# D3je: how to select all data points with specific value of particular data field

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have D3js heatmap graph that is made using code and reacting on click event:

```
  var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
    .data(availPlain)

   // abriged...

    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        // toggle special class for clicked item
        d3.select(this).classed("selectedClass",
            d3.select(this).classed("selectedClass") ? false : true);
        var isShown=d3.select(this).classed("selectedClass");              
    });
```

The looks of parameter **d** passed in on-click handler is as such:

```
 {"g":"16","station":"91","rid":"360"}
```

which is essentially an element of availPlain array or objects used to make a graph.
I want however to iterate over all d3 elements that have the same "g" value and toggle class for them as well. I am quite sure that some follow-up of select/selectAll shall be used but it is somewhat difficult to comprehend the actual code using documentaion (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections). So, how do I "classed" all items that have data condition "data.g==something"?

Answer (score 0):

Fugured this out:

```
.on("click", function (d, i) {
        heatMap.filter(function(dta){return (dta.g==d.g);})
        .classed("selectedClass", 
            d3.select(this).classed("selectedClass") ? false : true);

    });
```

Note that "this" in .classed and and in event handler function mean different objects.